# Validation CheckboxType symfony

Tags: symfony, validation, checkbox, types, assert

I don't know how to validate a checkbox with a @Assert.

Returns a string "1" if checked otherwise false

Step 1: create a class: SearchPlayerData.php to test my data (without ORM)
This form is not linked to a class

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class SearchPlayerData
{
     /**
     * (length=255, nullable=true) 
     * @Assert\???
     */
    public $tgg;

     /**
     * (length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\???
     */
    public $selection;
   ...
```

Step 2: SeachPlayerType

```
<?php
namespace App\Form;

use app\Entity\SearchPlayerData;

class SearchMultiType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

     $builder
            ->add('tgg', CheckboxType::class, [
                'label'             => "TGG", 
                'required'          => false,                
                'attr' => [
                    "class"         => "text-dark checkbox", 
                ], 
            ->add('selection', CheckboxType::class, [
                'label'             => "SELECTION", 
                'required'          => false,                
                'attr' => [
                    "class"         => "text-dark checkbox", 
                ], 
               ...
    
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            "data_class"    => SearchPlayerData::class
        ]);
    }
```

Etape 3 : Controller

```
    public function searchPlayers(Request $request, PlayerRepository $playerRepository)
    {
        $searchPlayerData = new SearchPlayerData(); 

        $form = $this->createForm(SearchPlayerType::class, $searchPlayerData, ["sect" => $sect]);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        ....
```

Do you have an idea or another solution. I would like to keep the checkbox field if possible

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `@Assert\Choice` with possible values.

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class SearchPlayerData
{
    /**
     * (length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Choice(callback={"App\Entity\SearchPlayerData", "getCheckboxAllowedValues"})
     */
    public $tgg;

    /**
     * (length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Choice(callback={"App\Entity\SearchPlayerData", "getCheckboxAllowedValues"})
     */
    public $selection;

    public static function getCheckboxAllowedValues()
    {
        return [1, false];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

But, there is something that I do not understand.
When i do :

```
 $data = $form->getData();
 var_dump($data);


output : 
["tgg"]=>
  bool(false)
["selection"]=>
  bool(true) if checked

return a boolean!!!
```

ps: it's different from a var_dump ($ _ POST). I understood this.
(return false or a string "1"];

So I fill in the values ​​true and false in function getCheckboxAllowedValues().
Ok it works;

However, why when in the inspector I change the value of the checkbox value = "%%%%", there is no error message. It validates the field to TRUE if the checkbox is checked and FALSE if it is not. Does this mean that value is never read?

Comment: Please check ChecboxType documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/checkbox.html. `Creates a single input checkbox. This should always be used for a field that has a boolean value: if the box is checked, the field will be set to true, if the box is unchecked, the value will be set to false.` CheckboxType designed with `true` or `false` value. Inside it use `BooleanToStringTransformer` https://github.com/symfony/form/blob/5.x/Extension/Core/Type/CheckboxType.php#L36

Comment: Thank you for the explanations and the demonstrations. Great